# Comparing resources in API 21 x API 23

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-resources

My app is running well in API 23 and above, but there seems to be a bug in it when I run it in API 21. I've narrowed it down to this piece of code:

```
if (myButton.getBackground().getConstantState() == ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.myDrawable, null).getConstantState())
{...}
```

In API 21 it always returns false (even when it shouldn't), so I guess one of those methods doesn't work in API 21.

Any ideas? Is there any other way (compatible with API 21 and above) to check if a button's background has a specific drawable assigned to it?

ps: my minsdk is 21, but Lint is not giving me any warnings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using ContextCompat:

```
ContextCompat.getDrawable(yourContext, R.drawable.myDrawable).getConstantState();
```

Comment: It worked. Do you have any idea why? Thanks for the help!

Comment: I can't be sure what the problem with the ResourceCompat because from the https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/res/ResourcesCompat.html#getDrawable(android.content.res.Resources, int, android.content.res.Resources.Theme) using null will the same with `getDrawable(resource)`. But when we using `ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.myDrawable, null).getConstantState()` Android Studio will complaining that it can return a null. Hence the problem arise.